# Attempting to create an empty list of classes and reference it with a pointer

Tags: c++

I have to create an empty list of classes and reference it with a pointer. 
Here is the very simple class I am attempting to do this with:

```
class Person {
    public:
    Person(string e_name){name=e_name;}
    string name;     // name of the person
    Person *next;    // pointer to the next person in the list
};
```

All I know is that the thing I need to do is to create of Class Person. I am supposed to reference it with "*emptylist" and when I show it's value with this macro:

```
#define show_addr_value(var, width){cout<<"address of " <<setw(width)<<left<<#var<<" is: &"<<&var<<"  "<<"contents of "<<setw(width)<<left<<#var<<" is: "<<var<<endl;}
```

I am supposed to get: "address of emptyList is: XXXXXXXXX contents of emptyList is: 0" and the value on the Ram Stack is nullptr.

Any help? I would ask my teacher if we still had in person classes but he isn't available for emailing at this time.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do here. Do you have a code sample that's not working?

Comment: I believe I do not understand how I am supposed to do the assignment either, I'm going to spend some time reading my textbook and see if the relevant chapters help and I just skipped over some stuff last time. After rethinking it I don't think this is the kind of question that's supposed to be on stack overflow...